# Group data by interval slice

Tags: r, shiny

Let's say i have this kind of data:

```
> head(data)
  year   type
1 1999   A
2 2018   B
3 2002   A
4 2001   B
5 2017   B
6 2017   A
```

How do i get to group the column 'year' by a interval defined by the user, let's say, `2`.

So the returning data would look like this:

```
> head(data)
   Ano       Type Freq
1 1999-2000   A   12
2 1999-2000   B   5
3 2001-2002   A   23
4 2001-2002   B   6
5 2003-2004   A   30
6 2003-2004   B   15
```

I'm using it along a `Shiny app`, and I've got this far, but it only works for one column:

```
period <- 1999:2004

n = 2
interval = split(period, ceiling(seq_along(period) / n))
year_interval = unlist(lapply(interval, function(x) {
  paste(min(x), max(x), sep = " - ")
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create data

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(10)
df <- tibble(year = sample(1999:2020, 30, T), type = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 30, T))
```

Group by intervals of N = 2 years

```
N <- 2
df %>% 
  mutate(g = year %/% N,
         years = paste0(g*N, '-', g*N + N - 1)) %>% 
  count(years, type)

# # A tibble: 20 x 3
# # Groups:   years [10]
#    years     type      n
#    <chr>     <chr> <int>
#  1 2000-2001 A         2
#  2 2000-2001 B         1
#  3 2002-2003 C         1
#  4 2004-2005 A         1
#  5 2004-2005 B         2
#  6 2004-2005 C         2
#  7 2006-2007 A         3
#  8 2006-2007 B         2
#  9 2008-2009 A         2
# 10 2008-2009 B         1
# 11 2010-2011 A         1
# 12 2010-2011 B         1
# 13 2012-2013 A         1
# 14 2012-2013 C         3
# 15 2014-2015 B         2
# 16 2014-2015 C         1
# 17 2016-2017 A         1
# 18 2016-2017 B         1
# 19 2016-2017 C         1
# 20 2018-2019 B         1
```

For N = 3

```
N <- 3
df %>% 
  mutate(g = year %/% N,
         years = paste0(g*N, '-', g*N + N - 1)) %>% 
  count(years, type)

# # A tibble: 18 x 3
# # Groups:   years [7]
#    years     type      n
#    <chr>     <chr> <int>
#  1 1998-2000 A         1
#  2 1998-2000 B         1
#  3 2001-2003 A         1
#  4 2001-2003 C         1
#  5 2004-2006 A         2
#  6 2004-2006 B         4
#  7 2004-2006 C         2
#  8 2007-2009 A         4
#  9 2007-2009 B         1
# 10 2010-2012 A         1
# 11 2010-2012 B         1
# 12 2010-2012 C         3
# 13 2013-2015 A         1
# 14 2013-2015 B         2
# 15 2013-2015 C         1
# 16 2016-2018 A         1
# 17 2016-2018 B         2
# 18 2016-2018 C         1
```

Comment: Hi there! I've tried your code, but this error message showed up:
Error in `[.data.frame`(., , .N, by = .(yr, type)) : 
  unused argument (by = .(yr, type))

Comment: On further reflection, my original solution wasn't very good. Try the new code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked just fine =)
But here's one question: after doing this, when i plot the graph using stat=identity and position=dodge, if there's only one type, the bar occupies both A and B type bar. Is there a way for this not to happen?

Comment: You can add `%>% 
  complete(years, type, fill = list(n = 0L))` to make sure each group has all the types. The added rows will have `n = 0` thanks to the third argument in `complete`.